# Simulation Cache is too heavy for SheepIt Render Farm

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation, cache, sheepit

I am using SheepIt to render my animation, but I have a problem with Simulation Cache.

I know that you need to include the Bake Cache folder to render in SheepIt. But the Smoke Cache I simulated is too heavy, around 1000-2000 frames, it required several GB, and SheepIt can't handle the file too large.

Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: The solution to this problem is to divide the animation into multiple parts.

Comment: yeah, I know that dividing it into multiple parts will resolve the problem. But for 2000 frames I need to divide into 6 or 7 parts. I just want to know if there is any way to reduce the cache size ??

Comment: The simplest way to reduce the cache size is to reduce the complexity of the simulation like the number of substeps. I don't think there's any lossless way easily available, because then it would be enabled by default…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to bake the simulation again (because I guess it took quite a while), there is absolutely nothing else than splitting it up.

For future bakes, you might consider the following things which influence the size of the smoke cache (the factors I mention might vary from project to project, they are just to give an idea how strong the influence can be):

- In general the smallest cache files are achieved by the default cache settings, using:

  *Format Volumes*: OpenVDB

  *Compression Volumes*: Blosc

  *Precision Volumes*: Half

This format generates the smallest files compared to the other possible options in the above categories. To get them even smaller, you have to enable *Adaptive Domain* (which is recommended anyway to reduce simulation time).

But beware of the *Is Resumable* option in the *Cache* settings. This is a nice feature to pause simulating, see if you like the result so far and resume simulating. But enabling it also makes the smoke cache more than twice as big as without it.

There is another option which can reduce the smoke cache, and that is *Dissolve*. When you make the smoke disappear over time, of course there is less data to be stored.

For all other settings on the domain the rule of thumb is: increasing a value increases the smoke cache. Some just a little, some more. *Timesteps Maximum/Minimum* just a little, *Resolution Divisions* a lot. Doubling the divisions results in quadrupling the smoke voxels (but fortunately just about tripling the smoke cache size).

Also an extreme factor for the smoke cache size is enabling *Noise*. With the default settings, a smoke cache with noise is easily 2.5 times larger than without noise.

These are just a few examples for the *Domain* settings. The settings of the *Flow* object influence the smoke cache as well of course, like the *Substeps* although they are almost negligible in relation to changes in the *Domain* settings. Very high *Surface Emission* values result in generating more smoke and can be an important factor as well.

As for the *Domain*, the rule of thumb for the *Flow* object also is increasing a value usually increases the smoke cache size.

There might be other things have more or less influence on the cahce size. For example open boundaries that let the smoke leave the domain can reduce the amount of data like *Dissolve*, while keeping the smoke inside with closed boundaries also keeps a high amount of data.

All in all you can say, higher values create larger smoke caches and when planning on reducing the size you especially have to think about:

- Do you really need the *Resolution Divisions* as high as they are?
- Do you really need the *Is Resumable* option, because this is a
  very high factor?
- And the other important factor, how much *Noise* do
  you really need? Do you need it at all, and if so how high does the
  *Upres Factor* or *Strength* need to be?
- Enable *Adaptive Domain* because it can save simulation time and disk space.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and I suspect you know it already. The maximum uploaded file size for SheepIt render farm is 750 MB currently [as they clearly specify on their upload page](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/getstarted) and several gigabytes are more than 750 MB. So no, there is no way to handle this problem.